# Does aggregating ordinal data destroy the signal?

Tags: ordinal-data, ordered-logit, binning

In an university assignment we are being asked to perform ordinal regression on wine data, predicting the quality of wine on a scale of 1 to 3, where 1 = inferior, 2 = average, 3 = superior.

So far all ordinal regression methods I have tried on the data set performed poorly. Interestingly, the ordinal regression methods seem to perform worse than their non-ordinal counterparts: ordinal forest performed worse than random forest, SVOREX and SVORIM (Chu et al. 2005) performed worse than the vanilla SVM with radial kernel, etc.

After some research I found that for this assignment the profs aggregated the ratings from another wine dataset rated on a scale of 1 to 10(so [1:3] maps to 1, [4:6] to 2, etc). Does this explain why ordinal regression methods performed so poorly? More generally, does aggregating ordinal data like this destroy the underlying "ordinal" signal?

Comment: Can you link to the data? Well, clearly aggregating data in general is loosing information .... but without more information/context I am afraid not much more can be said.

Comment: The original data can be found here on the UCI website: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/ . The dataset used is the white wine dataset.

Comment: If these aggregated data contain a vector of frequency weights, one would hope that you have correctly supplied these to the regression procedure that you are attempting to do... Nevertheless, "non-ordinal" is not clear, and even if it is the wrong procedure, sometimes the wrong procedure yields better results when validating in-sample or out-of-sample, but it is a complete fluke. (you don't mention on what basis you claim the "non-ordinal" model is "better").

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Not necessarily. If you have categorical data, "aggregation" refers to a representation of data. You can append a vector of weights, constant 1, to any dataset and call it "aggregated". Collapse duplicate rows in categorical data, and it is an efficient representation. "Binning" values, like with dichotomization, is a loss of information.

Comment: @AdamO Non-ordinal counterparts refer to the original algorithms that simply does classification (ignores the ranking information).

Comment: For each algorithm I did the train/test split with a different random seed and repeat it100 times. I examined the distributions of the accuracies for the different methods to conclude that one method was better than the other.